# Java: Problem with Code for Database Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to compile this Java Code. so I can connect myself to a local Oracle database.
But my code doesn't work correcty. It fails at:

```
Driver myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
```

Could you please tell me how i replace this line ?

```
package DB_Oracle_Connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class dbconf {

private String connstr;
private Connection connect;
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        connstr = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";

        try {
                String uname = "scott";
                String pass = "tiger";

                Driver myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
                DriverManager.registerDriver( myDriver );                  


                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, uname, pass);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

            return connect;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message exactly?

Comment: As suggested by @ShivamPuri, add the stacktrace of the error from the application log.

Answer (score 1):

Driver's class path should be oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver() whereas you have written it as oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()

Comment: I have change thje value to Driver myDriver = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver(); But the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use Class.forName to load the driver.
See the below code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Dbconf {

    private String connstr;
    private Connection connect;

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        connstr = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";

        try {
            String uname = "scott";
            String pass = "tiger";

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, uname, pass);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return connect;
    }
```

Comment: I have changed my code Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); This solves my complilation problem. But when i execute my program i get the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Add below JAR to your classpath. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadojdbc6jar.htm

Comment: Hello I had to add ojdbc8.jar in eclipse for my project. Now I can connect to my database. Thank you !